# if condition not working in javascript, only the else part executes

Tags: javascript, html

The code is running fine, but the if condition is not working, displays NA everytime the submit button is clicked.
 Please find below the HTML and Javascript code.

Please check.

The HTML part-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <label style="color:blue;margin-left:30px;">Category:</label>
    <input type="text" list="cat" />
    <datalist id="cat">
      <option value="Air Conditioner">
      <option value="Chimney & Hoods">
    </datalist>
   <br><br>
   <label style="color:blue;margin-left:30px;">Brand:</label>
   <input type="text" list="brand" />

   <datalist id="brand">
     <option value="abc">
     <option value="pqr">
     <option value="xyz">
     <option value="aaa">
     <option value="bbb">
   </datalist>
   <br><br>

   <button onclick="change()">Submit</button>
   <br><br>  

   <label>Segmentation:</label>
   <input type="text" id="segmentation" name="" value=""><br><br>
  </body>
</html>
```

The Javascript part-

```
<script>
/*the javascript function not working correctly*/
function change() {
  if (((document.getElementById("cat").value =='Air Conditioner') && ((document.getElementById("brand").value == 'abc')||(document.getElementById("brand").value =='pqr')))
    || ((document.getElementById("cat").value =='Chimney & Hoods') && ((document.getElementById("brand").value =='Glen')||                                                                                      (document.getElementById("brand").value =='aaa')||                              (document.getElementById("brand").value =='pqr'))))
  {
    document.getElementById("segmentation").value = 'Service';
  }     /*this condition not working*/  
  else {
    document.getElementById("segmentation").value = 'NA';
  }     
}
```

Comment: There is no element with id "cat" in your html, is that whole html?

Comment: where is the id cat?? I dint see. Please post complete code so that we can help.

Comment: I would suggest you 2 things: (1) do `var val = document.getElementById("brand").value` and (2) simplify your ifs by breaking them down to `if...else if... else`, you dont want to be reading this in 6 months time!

Comment: I think you missed div with id cat... could update your code..

Comment: I think, you could have simplified your method as following to identify the problem.

function change() {
 var cat = document.getElementById("cat").value;
 var brand = document.getElementById("brand").value;
 
 if(
  (cat == 'Air Conditioner' && (brand == 'abc' || brand == 'pqr'))
  ||
  (cat == 'Chimney & Hoods' && (brand == 'Glen' || brand == 'aaa' || brand == 'pqr')) 
 ){
  document.getElementById("segmentation").value = 'Service';
 }else{
  document.getElementById("segmentation").value = 'NA';
 }
}

Comment: what is the `cat` id??

Comment: my bad!..missed out the cat id..it was there in the program..still not running!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Use `<input>` element's id to get the value of `<datalist>` element.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script>
/*the javascript function not working correctly*/
function change() {

        if (((document.getElementById("cat1").value =='Air Conditioner') && ((document.getElementById("brandName").value == 'abc')||
                                                                            (document.getElementById("brandName").value =='pqr')))



        || ((document.getElementById("cat1").value =='Chimney & Hoods') && ((document.getElementById("brandName").value =='Glen')||
                                                                                    (document.getElementById("brandName").value =='aaa')||
                                                                                    (document.getElementById("brandName").value =='pqr'))))
      {
      document.getElementById("segmentation").value = 'Service';

        }       
    else {
        document.getElementById("segmentation").value = 'NA';
        }       
  }

</script>
    </head>
    <body>
  <label style="color:blue;margin-left:30px;">Category:</label>
  <input type="text" list="cat" id="cat1" />
  <datalist id="cat">
  <option value="Air Conditioner">
  <option value="Chimney & Hoods">
  </datalist>
 <br><br>
<label style="color:blue;margin-left:30px;">Brand:</label>
<input type="text" list="brand" id="brandName"/>
<datalist id="brand">
<option value="abc">
<option value="pqr">
<option value="xyz">
<option value="aaa">
<option value="bbb">
 </datalist>
<br><br>
<button onclick="change()">Submit</button>
<br><br>  
<label>Segmentation:</label>
<input type="text" id="segmentation" name="" value=""><br><br>
</body>
</html>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Meenakshi..but can you please specify the changes you have made to the if else loop???

Comment: instead of (document.getElementById("cat") use (document.getElementById("cat1") and  replace (document.getElementById("brand") with (document.getElementById("brandName") i.e. use the id's of input tag to get value of datalist tag.

Comment: Thanks a ton @Meenakshi..it was really helpful!